# Can SO be used as an free image storing service?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images

On Stack Overflow you can upload images onto your post.  When you do, they get an `imgur.com` URL where they stay.

**Problem**

If you upload an image, then it gets added to your to-be post.  A link appears at the bottom with something like

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/imagename.png
```

You can copy that link, cancel your post, and use the link anywhere you want to use it.  I think that these image URLs do not get deleted because, if they did, then questions might have images that don't exist.

**(Possible) Solution**

If the post gets cancelled, then remove the pictures for any image links uploaded.  This way, you won't be able to use them (because you cancelled your post).

Comment: @JeanneDark: I do not think that is relevant; my point is that you can use `imgur.com` to store your own images, not why we use `imgur.com`.

Comment: So you are asking if you can use [imgur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur), an " image sharing community and image host", to host pictures? Yes, you can.

Comment: @JeanneDark: I should probably change the title of the question.  I am saying that you can use it, just in a way that you shouldn't.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? Because it doesn't seem to be related to Stack Exchange at all. If I'm reading this correctly, you're concerned that somebody could upload an image and get a permanent link to imgur. Well, *anybody* can already do that. You can go to imgur.com and upload an image without having a registration. there are applications that have an option to directly upload images to Imgur and the image would be hosted indefinitely. I'm pretty sure there is an API for this. So any "abuse" seems to be freely tolerated by the service which isn't even affiliated with SE.

Answer (score 14):

> If the post gets cancelled, then remove the pictures for any image links uploaded.

No, [that breaks my workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/).

I often start a new post to upload images so I can use those links in a comment or chat message. Comments don't have an image uploader and image uploader in chat is ...

I'm pretty sure SE will take action when the abuse pattern exceeds certain thresholds. As said by [balpha (an SE developer at the time)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137057/158100):

> It's obviously easy for us to query for the information "Which images
> were ever legitimately used", and Imgur has an easy-to-use API. In
> other words, if we become aware of larger scale abuse [...] then we're
> talking about a fairly limited amount of dev work that would be
> necessary to do some house cleaning in our Imgur account, and suddenly
> your images are gone.

That sounds like a healthier approach that better mitigates problems and prevent annoying users upfront that have no intent to abuse the services offered.

Answer (score 6):

Fundamentally speaking, Imgur is storing the images, and Imgur is used as a free image storing service the world over.

So no, Stack Overflow *itself* couldn't be an image repo, but Imgur can be.

Bear in mind that the barrier to "abuse" is pretty damn high; you have to create a post that has the images you want in such a way that:

- they are on-topic for the site you're posting them on,
- are not visible on the post if they're *not* on-topic, and
- can survive several hundreds of people who want to edit posts from touching them.

Assuredly there may be some other details about image or data expiry if the link isn't used anywhere on the site, but I don't know about that.

All of that is much much harder to deal with rather than uploading it to just Imgur in the first place.

Comment: If you edit a post, add an image, copy the URL, and cancel the edit, you get the URL without having to actually publish the edit (e.g. I made https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdBO4.jpg without actually using it in any posts, and I did it in well under 30 seconds). I don't agree that "all of that is much much harder to deal with than uploading it to just Imgur in the first place".

Comment: @PikalèSorcereroftheWhales:  That's one image, but "abuse" would have it on several orders of magnitude more images that you'd want to put on the site.  Let's start there.  Second, no one really knows the details of how Imgur retains or expires images on Stack Overflow, so that image could be here today and gone tomorrow.  (It'd make sense for them to clean it up if it's not attached to a post or revision but we don't know.)  Third, Imgur itself has processes to reap images that are known to be **bad**, so the paths to wanton abuse of a convenience that Stack provides is still...slim.

Comment: @PikalèSorcereroftheWhales:  That said, you could upload more images if you just went to Imgur's main site.  You've got expectations about how long the image lasts (pretty much indefinitely), and there's no concern about any sudden rule changes impacting that.  What's more, it's simply more time effective (again, think on orders of magnitude here).

Comment: It is true that the expiration details are unclear; I can't find any at the moment, but I have other i.stack.imgur URLs that have lasted many months. I haven't seen any evidence of image removals/cleanups; perhaps there still are, but I am not aware of them. I don't think OP was referring to inappropriate-type images, but yes, that form of image abuse is unlikely. Normal imgur may be quicker, yes, but as I said before, it's not hard or time-consuming to use i.stack.imgur either; but I agree when uploading mass quantities, imgur is quicker.